# Don’t add space between paragraphs of the same style

Tags: adobe-indesign, book

Rather new at book body design. Having a little problem. I know there are similar questions here, but it didn't really solve my specifics.

I have loads of quotes in my book that I will indent a little. I have a paragraph style for that, with space before and space after (a lines worth). I could of course apply those manually, but prefer not to. So far all good.

The problem is when there is a quoted conversation between two or more people. The writer wants each answer/comment starting on a new line. With my paragraphs' style I get a blank line between each new comment. Some of those conversations are like:

```
What do you think?

Sorry?

Would you?

Yes

Are you sure?

Not really
```

… and so on.

Thus creating terribly long and ugly segments. So I want there to be no blank line between each new comment. How do I do this? Basically I would like the "space before" and "space after" to only apply when the quote paragraphs meet my body style, and not when another quote paragraph comes.

I tried to solve it by using forced line brakes between comments, so every quote would be just one paragraph. That doesn't work with my justified type through as it then justifies that last line, however few characters there are.

Answer (score 1):

Make all paragraphs styles with only **space before** (black paragraphs at the image), and for conversations, another paragraph style without this space (red paragraphs):

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks. I do need that space before though. Could insert it manually I guess. But it is a 400 page book and there are quotes on probably 200 hundred of them. What I did was using left-aligned text instead of justified in the quotes and then changed all the returns to hard returns. Looks pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the feature you want is on the Paragraph Style Options page. It’s the “Space Between Paragraphs Using Same Style” feature. Set that to zero (or whatever value you like), and then you’ll have total and separate control over “Space Before”, “Space After”, and intra-list spacing.

I don’t remember when this feature was introduced. It’s relatively new, but I think it’s at least a couple years old (I’m using Adobe InDesign 17.4).

Comment: I submitted a feature request for this in May 2017, and it was accepted for inclusion by Adobe soon after. It made it to prerelease versions in June 2018, so it was probably included in public versions from MAX 2018, I would guess.